# Angular Js attribute routing issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to create the following url:

http://example.com/app/rfidportals/update/6ce3cc59-aca1-48d8-8db3-7861859b4dc1/createreader

For that to work, I have used angular stateProvider. My definition is below:

```
---
$stateProvider
.state('app.rfidportals.createrfidreader', {
  url :'/update/:id/createrfidreader',
  templateUrl : Route.base('rfidportals/updaterfidportal.html'),
  resolve:{
    assets: Route.require('toaster')
  }
})
---
```

However, the url that I am getting is below:
http://example.com/app/rfidportals/update//createrfidreader

Here is how I am invoking the Url (I have confirmed that Id is not null):

```
<a ui-sref="app.rfidportals.createrfidreader({id : vm.Model.Id})" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <em class="sidebar-item-icon"></em>
        <span>Create Rfid Reader</span>
     </a>
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and reading through documentation I was able to solve the problem by using the below from inside the angular controller.

> $state.go

```
vm.createnewreader = function(){
  $state.go('app.rfidportals.createrfidreader',{id:portalId});
};
```

In the view I binded the `ng-click`

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-Success" ng-click="reader.createnewreader()">Create Rfid Reader
        </button>
```